# LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined in empty project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created a Visual C++ empty project with Visual Studio 2017 15.3.4 Community edition selecting Visual C++ -> General -> Empty project from wizard. I wanted to create a C++ library (static or dynamic).

But when I compile it I get this message:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

I have right clicked on Project, select Properties, Linker and advanced and Entry Point option is empty.

What do I have to put there?

Is there another better option to create a C++ library?

Comment: Use the library template to create a library.

Comment: What's the configuration type of your project? It's probably exe

Comment: @Alf Maybe I don`t have that template installed because I haven't found it. I thought that an empty project is the project I need, but I'm wrong (I suppose).

Comment: @VansFannel: I'm sorry. Things have changed recently. They've let loose some dumb person there. I'm looking but I don't see the library project templates yet. It's just amazing that they manage to f**k that up.

Comment: Project properties/General/Configuration Type - should be dll or lib not exe

Comment: I can see the route that the dumb person has followed in managing to remove the static library template. First it was incorporated into the ["WIn32 console program" template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp), just an option in that wizard. Then *the wizard was removed* to simplify things. And with the wizard gone, so also the option to select static library up front. You just have to tweak the project properties... :(

Comment: Upvoted the question, it's timely. But **please provide VS version and update**. That's very relevant here.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The version is 15.3.4

Comment: That's the latest (currently), and the reason you lack a static library project template or wizard option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library does not have an entrypoint, so you can tell that the project is not configured correctly.  The specific setting you forgot to change is Project > Properties > General > Configuration Type.  Select "Static library (.lib)".

This went wrong because you started from scratch, having to get dozens of settings right is never not a problem.  For VS2017 RTM you'll favor starting from Win32 > Win32 Project > Next > "Static library" radio button.  Maybe that changed, I haven't kept it updated because I've seen too many nasty bug reports for 15.3.x

Comment: Thanks. Not it compiles. But i don't have the option Win32 > Win32 Project > Next > "Static library" in project creation wizard. Maybe I don't have installed that add-on in Visual Studio.

Comment: **−1** Re "Beware that the chatter in the comments is highly inaccurate, this has been around for more than 20 years and still works the way it always did in VS2017", you'd better check your facts. Update to 15.3.4.

Comment: Well, you could just edit it.  Glad I could shame you into posting an actually useful answer, we're all ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant: I wonder how you imagine that you shamed me. If anything, you should be ashamed of your characterizations, which turned out to be false.

Comment: I don't know why people has downvoted your question if this answer answers my question.

Comment: I needed to be reminded again why posting answers in the [c++] tag is such a bad idea.  Please do me a favor and unmark the post.  I'll merge the relevant part into the other answer and delete this one.

Answer (score 3):

To create a static library in VS 2017 version 15.3.4, first select the "Windows Desktop Wizard" template,

[image]

In the wizard dialog that pops up, change the application type to static library:

[image]

You might also want to turn off precompiled headers, since with Visual C++ that gives a non-standard preprocessor behavior.