# Where visual studio c++ project wizard gone in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.3.3), when I creating new c++ project (console or window application) there is no wizard window where I can check "empty project" , set application type etc. How can I bring it back (this wizard) ?

Comment: It was replaced in one of the 15.3 updates.  The project templates were renamed and moved into another category.  [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268966/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant that was that ;-) Thx ;-) Do you know why they make this change ?

Comment: Not for a fact, but that wizard was stone cold old.  It used JavaScript in a WebBrowser, that was never not a problem.  Hard to adapt to the File > Export Template feature, discontinued in VS2017 and hopefully they'll bring it back.  And surely nobody at MSFT is left that still knows how it works.